# GAE: Separating tests from app code

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, junit

I am writing a small Google App Engine application in Java using Eclipse. My code is stored in `src/cinemasderot`, and my tests are stored in `src/tests`.

Quoting the [Google App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting):

> Tip: It is good practice to store your unit tests in a different
>   location than your application code. Also avoid deploying JUnit and
>   other testing packages with your application.

**How can I separate the tests from the app code?** I'd like the test files not to be deployed to the app server, and have a separate classpath file for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already separated the code and tests in separate directories, which is the most important step.  In the very early days of jUnit it was more common to see people putting the tests in the same directory as the production code.  I guess some people might still do that.  Today best practice is to use separate source roots but use parallel package structures.  Which is what it appears you've done.

Now the question is, how are you building your application?  Ant, Maven, the GAE Eclipse plugin, etc?  I'm not real familiar with GAE, but in general, you should be sure to compile the production and test code using separate commands and put the compiled output in separate directories.  And then when you create a Jar or War file to deploy, only include the production code.